# Making Inline text between icons and text in flutter ios mobile App

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have made a widget for settings in flutter for ios mobile app but i am facing the issue for adjusting the text inline between the icons and text

I am trying to inlining the content between the icons and text in the widget and I am getting the text and icons are uneven for inlining.

Here's my code for ios mobile app: -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaRvF.jpg)

Comment: There are multiple things you need to check one by one. First of all try to add TextAlign.center in your Text widget. If this solution not fulfil your requirement add padding property in leading icon and set EdgeInsects.zero. If still this issue present then make your custom listtile using Row..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in **line 181** with the subtitle, insted of putting empty string if subtitle is null, you should replace it with empty **SizedBox()** or a **Container()**

Try code below :

```
subtitle: subtitle == null ? SizedBox() : TextWidget(
 text: subtitle
)
```